# Adding user in a group in ldap php

Tags: php, ldap

I have a problem when I tried to add a user in a group.
I search it and I find to do that:

```
$connexion=ldap_connect("ADsevrer");
ldap_set_option($connexion,LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION,3);
ldap_set_option($connexion, LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS,0);
ldap_set_option($connexion, LDAP_OPT_SIZELIMIT, 100000000);
$session=ldap_bind($connexion,$user."@toto.ch",$mdp);
ldap_mod_add($connexion, 'CN=ProfsToto_Wifi,OU=Toto-ProfsWIFI,OU=Professeurs,DC=toto,DC=ch', $entry);
```

But it returns:

```
( ! ) Warning: ldap_mod_add(): Modify: Insufficient access
```

And I think it's logic because I don't use the authentification variable but if I write:

```
ldap_mod_add($session, 'CN=ProfsToto_Wifi,OU=Toto-ProfsWIFI,OU=Professeurs,DC=toto,DC=ch', $entry);
```

I have this error:

```
Warning: ldap_mod_add() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given
```

Can anyone help me?

best regards

Comment: What is in `$session` ?

Comment: There is the LDAP binding.
-> $session=ldap_bind($connexion,$user."@toto.ch",$mdp);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay sorry, I find the answer.
You have to binding with the Administrator rights.
I just don't understand that even don't use the $session variable, you're connect.
So I just connect with:

```
$session=ldap_bind($connexion,"administrator@toto.ch","Password");
```

And after doing:

```
ldap_mod_add($connexion, 'CN=ProfsToto_Wifi,OU=Toto-ProfsWIFI,OU=Professeurs,DC=toto,DC=ch', $entry);
```